# Bootstrap accordion collapse content callback is not smooth

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

To know better what I mean, please access my code here https://jsfiddle.net/gnhta7q8/

I don't want to attach the whole file of bootstrap.css to my website. So I have just imported the CSS code from it to my stylesheet I will need for the collapse. But still this is a problem concerning the content will be delayed to be hidden when calling back the panel.
So something is still missing in my code, what is it? Who will be professional enough to solve my problem?
Thanks

My code

**HTML**

```
<div class="panel-group" id="accordion">
<div class="panel panel-default">
  <div class="panel-heading">
    <h4 class="panel-title">
      <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapse1">Collapsible Group 1</a>
    </h4>
  </div>
  <div id="collapse1" class="panel-collapse collapse">
    <div class="panel-body">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit,
.</div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="panel panel-default">
  <div class="panel-heading">
    <h4 class="panel-title">
      <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapse2">Collapsible Group 2</a>
    </h4>
  </div>
  <div id="collapse2" class="panel-collapse collapse">
    <div class="panel-body">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit,
</div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="panel panel-default">
  <div class="panel-heading">
     <h4 class="panel-title">
         <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion"                 href="#collapse3">Collapsible Group 3</a>
    </h4>
   </div>
   <div id="collapse3" class="panel-collapse collapse">
    <div class="panel-body">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur     adipisicing elit,
.</div>
  </div>
</div>
  </div>
```

**CSS**

```
.panel-group 
{
margin-bottom: 20px;
}
.panel-group .panel 
{
margin-bottom: 0;
border-radius: 4px;
}
.panel-default 
{
border-color: #ddd;
}
.panel 
{
margin-bottom: 20px;
background-color: #fff;
border: 1px solid transparent;
border-radius: 4px;
-webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,.05);
box-shadow: 0 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,.05);
}
.panel-default > .panel-heading 
{
color: #333;
background-color: #f5f5f5;
border-color: #ddd;
}
.panel-group .panel-heading 
{
border-bottom: 0;
}
.panel-heading 
{
padding: 10px 15px;
border-bottom: 1px solid transparent;
border-top-left-radius: 3px;
border-top-right-radius: 3px;
}
.panel-title 
{
margin-top: 0;
margin-bottom: 0;
font-size: 16px;
color: inherit;
}
.collapse.in 
{
display: block;
}
.collapse 
{
display: none;
}
.panel-body::after
{
clear: both;
}
.panel-body::after, .panel-body::before,
{
display: table;
content: " ";
}
.panel-default > .panel-heading + .panel-collapse > .panel-body 
{
border-top-color: #ddd;
}
.panel-group .panel-heading + .panel-collapse > .panel-body 
{
border-top: 1px solid #ddd;
color: #000;
}
.panel-body 
{
padding: 15px;
}
.panel-group .panel + .panel 
{
margin-top: 5px;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add .collapsing class. please check out the [FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/NayanaDas/gnhta7q8/4/)

```
.collapsing {
  position: relative;
  height: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  -webkit-transition: height .35s ease;
       -o-transition: height .35s ease;
          transition: height .35s ease;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Try to add this to your CSS

```
.collapsing {
  position: relative;
  height: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.2s; /* Safari */
  transition: all 0.2s;
}
```

Comment: Perfect. Thank you @Dan Wears Prada

Comment: Thanks! Smart of you not including the whole css file